# Inserindo TextView em uma ListView

Tags: android, listview, textview

Estou com um problema. Preciso inserir um textview dentro de uma listview.

Segue o método base

```
class MyKickAssAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
    //...

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        TextView tv;

        // fazer a inserção aqui

        tv.setText("Hello Ideais!");
        return tv;
    }
}
```

Todos os métodos que achei estavam retornando a convertView em vez da textview proposta na amostra.

Estou um pouco perdido.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primeiro terá de criar um *Layout* que representará cada uma das linhas da *ListView*. Neste seu caso será um *LinearLayout* com um *TextView* dentro.

**res/layout/item_lista.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

O método `getView()` do *Adapter* é chamado sempre que uma nova linha da lista necessita de ser apresentado, se a `convertView` for `null` utilize o *LayoutInflater* para converter o *layout* em um objecto *View* e atribua-o a ela.

Utilize o método `findViewById()` para obter uma referência ao *TextView*, coloque nele o valor correspondente a essa linha, retorne a `convertView`.

```
public class MyKickAssAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<String> oMeuArray;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    MyKickAssAdapter(Context context, ArrayList oMeuArray){
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.context = context;
        this.oMeuArray = oMeuArray;
    }
    //...

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        TextView tv;

        if(convertView == null){
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_lista, parent, false);
        }

        tv = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
        tv.setText(oSeuArray.get(i));
        //Se cada linha tivesse mais views eram actualizadas aqui
        ...
        ...
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Isto é o básico, se quiser veja [aqui](http://www.piwai.info/android-adapter-good-practices/) uma forma mais correta/eficiente de fazer.